# Call void method and pass trought arguments RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm looking for a better to do this :

```
mRestService.login(email, password) // Login user in
                .flatMap(user -> Observable.zip(
                        mRestService.start(user._token), // Start his session
                        Observable.just(user),
                        (v, u) -> (User) u // Pass user throught
                ))
                .subscribe(user -> {
                }, throwable -> {                     
                });
```

But I coudn't come up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

the `start` method on the `mRestService` perform a side effect. So you can use `doOnNext` method which is here for this sort of side effect.

```
 mRerstService.login(email, password)
              .doOnNext(u -> mRestService.start(user._token))
              .subscribe();
```

Comment: Humm, I realized, that it call my start method indeed but in case the method fail my general onError method is not called. (Witch was the case before)

Comment: what is your "general" on error ? if an error occur in the `doOnNext`, it will notifiy the downstream with `onError`

Comment: mRestService.start(user._token) is an observable method that returns Observable<Void>

Comment: so you'll have to flatMap. `flatMap(u -> mRestService.start(user._token).concatWith(Observable.just(u)).subscribe()`

Answer (score 0):

You should call mRestService.start(user._token) in flatMap. The user object will be passed to subscribe where you can use it.

```
 mRestService.login(email, password) // Login user in
                .flatMap((user -> mRestService.start(user._token)))
                .subscribe(user -> {
                }, throwable -> {
                });
```

Comment: Start is retunrning an Observable<Void> and I want to keep the User